# Error: No value associated with key CodingKeys

Tags: json, swift, api

I'm trying to fetch JSON data from a currency API. But I'm getting the below error:

> CurrencyConverter[32130:2625405] [boringssl]
> boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics
> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "rates", intValue: nil),
> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No
> value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "rates", intValue:
> nil) ("rates").", underlyingError: nil))

This is my View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet var priceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchJSON()
    }
    
    //MARK: - Method
    
    func fetchJSON() {
        guard let url = URL(string:"https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/xxx/latest/TRY") else { return }
```

"xxx" includes my API key

```
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            // handle any errors if there are any
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            //safely unwrap the data
            guard let safeData = data else { return }

            // decode the JSON Data
            do {
                let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(ExchangeRates.self, from: safeData)
                print(results.rates)
            } catch {
              print(error)

            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

This is the struct for the ExchangeRater:

```
import Foundation

struct ExchangeRates: Codable {
    
    let rates: [String: Double]
    
    
}
```

Comment: When I just type https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/xxx/latest/TRY in the browser it says in an inactive account!?

Comment: Looking at the JSON for that api, it looks like the property is called `"conversion_rates"`. That has to match your struct. You could rename the property in `ExchangeRates` to `conversion_rates`. Or call it `conversionRates` and use the `.snakeCase` decoding strategy on your decoder. Or add a `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey` to your struct and have a case called `rates = "conversion_rates"`

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld that's because the "xxx" part includes my API key in my actual code.

Comment: aha ofc. Sorry!